# Can't resolve application context with hilt/dagger for shared preferences repository

Tags: kotlin, singleton, sharedpreferences, dagger-hilt

Attempting to implement shared preferences as a singleton to store user preferences in my app. I've got dagger and hilt implemented in places across the app but my understanding of it is still quite shakey.

Here is my keyvalue store class

```
class KeyValueStore @Inject constructor(
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
) {

    fun getString(key: SharedPreferenceKey) = sharedPreferences.getString(key.name, "")

    fun getBoolean(key: SharedPreferenceKey) = sharedPreferences.getBoolean((key.name), false)

    fun setString(vararg values: Pair <SharedPreferenceKey, String>) = sharedPreferences.edit{
        values.forEach { (key, value)  ->
            putString(key.name, value)
        }
    }

    fun setBoolean(vararg values: Pair <SharedPreferenceKey, Boolean>) = sharedPreferences.edit{
        values.forEach { (key, value)  ->
            putBoolean(key.name, value)
        }
    }

    fun clearValue(key: SharedPreferenceKey) = sharedPreferences.edit{
        remove(key.name)
    }

    fun clear() = sharedPreferences.edit{
        clear()
    }
}
```

Then in my appModule I attempt to intialise the singleton

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun sharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext context: Context): SharedPreferences{
        return sharedPreferences(context)
    }
}
```

There are other repositories initialised here as well used for my data access (via objectbox) and that has been working for a while but i just copied out the stuff relevant for the shared preferences.

I attempt to use the keyvaluestore in my main activity

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var splashViewModel: SplashViewModel
    @Inject lateinit var keyValueStore: KeyValueStore


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        var keepSplashOnScreen = true
        val delay = 1000L

        installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition { keepSplashOnScreen }
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ keepSplashOnScreen = false }, delay)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        initialiseApp()

        setContent {
            FL_DatatrackerTheme {
                val screen by splashViewModel.startDestination
                SetupNavGraph(startDestination = screen)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initialiseApp(){
        if(!keyValueStore.getBoolean(SettingsKeys.ONBOARDING_COMPLETE)){
            keyValueStore.setBoolean(Pair(SettingsKeys.ONBOARDING_COMPLETE, false))
            keyValueStore.setString(Pair(SettingsKeys.CURRENT_PRESET, "Default"))
        }
    }
}
```

And also try to use the keyValueStore in the SplashScreen in a view model. This class handles an onboarding section that I show before the first screen.

```
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val keyValueStore: KeyValueStore
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _isLoading: MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(true)

    private val _startDestination: MutableState<String> = mutableStateOf(Screen.Welcome.route)
    val startDestination: State<String> = _startDestination

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (keyValueStore.getBoolean(SettingsKeys.ONBOARDING_COMPLETE)) {
                _startDestination.value = Screen.HomeScreen.route
            } else {
                _startDestination.value = Screen.Welcome.route
            }
        }
        _isLoading.value = false
    }
}
```

All looks good and builds but then i get a stack overflow error

```
 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jorotayo.fl_datatracker, PID: 5186 java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8188KB
at com.jorotayo.fl_datatracker.dependencyInjection.AppModule.sharedPreferences(Unknown Source:2)
at com.jorotayo.fl_datatracker.dependencyInjection.AppModule.sharedPreferences(AppModule.kt:131)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Have tried various types of shared preferences initialisations and even trying to retrieve at application context in different ways. This is the furthest i got because the app actually builds. Other things wouldn't even build

**Edit: Found my solution**

It was how I was calling shared Preferences.
Should have been

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun sharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext context: Context): SharedPreferences {
    return context.getSharedPreferences("AppPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
}
```